# Is this use of a conjunction correct?

Tags: conjunctions

Is the way 'and' is used at the start of the second sentence below correct? Someone that is reviewing my writing said that its an 'egregious grammar error'. Am I missing something? It seems correct to me.

> Finance is grounded in both the theory and practice. And I’m intrinsically attracted by the fundamental concepts and how they behave once they’re brought into society.

Comment: Starting with *and*, *but*, and *or* is startling, but no longer incorrect. I use it very selectively, and you could use better connectors here. Also, "intrinsically" is not ideal. Perhaps too fancy here. Sentence #2 mostly says you like sentence #1.